# Google Recaptcha in ASP.net 4.7.2

Tags: asp.net, recaptcha

I am trying to install Recaptcha in my project. In order to accomplish that, I downloaded

```
 recaptcha-dotnet-1.0.5.0-binary.zip
```

from here

```
https://code.google.com/archive/p/recaptcha/downloads
```

I unzipped the zip file and placed the Recpatcha in my project references:

I added Recaptcha in my asp.net page like so:

[image]

I put the below tag in my asp.net web form

```
  <%@ Register TagPrefix="recaptcha" Namespace="Recaptcha" Assembly="Recaptcha" %>
```

then I added the code in my aspx page like so:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

          <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl
              ID="recaptcha"
              runat="server"
              Theme="red"
              PublicKey="xxxx"
              PrivateKey="xxxxx"
              />

          <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" style="height: 26px" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

when I run the asp.net application by pressing F5. I don't see anything on my web page except the submit button:

[image]

I am not sure what am I doing wrong and how can I see Recaptcha.

I also followed this article :

```
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/884193/Google-ReCaptcha-ASP-net-Control
```

and put the same GoogleREcaptcha that is mentioned in the article. I am getting the following error if I use the same dll as mentioned in the article

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where exactly did you place the tag? In a Web Form, in a Master Page? Can you post a more detailed code example?

Comment: I edited my question. I am placing the tag in  a webform.aspx .Thanks for replying back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your code-behind? In any case, there are three versions of the Google ReCaptcha. Version 1.0 which you are using from an old archive is **deprecated**. At a minimum you should be using [version](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/old/docs/aspnet) [2.0](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq)

Here is an article which I often refer to when adding ReCaptcha 2.0 to Web Forms projects. If you follow these steps it should work for you:

[Google ReCaptcha 2.0 - ASP.NET Control](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/884193/Google-ReCaptcha-ASP-net-Control)

Bear in mind the the keys you register for your live site will not work on your local machine. You can obtain free dev keys for developing locally.

Comment: I followed this article that you mentioned and I am getting this error:  @__ctrl = ((GoogleReCaptcha.GoogleReCaptcha)(System.Web.HttpRuntime.WebObjectActivator.GetService(typeof(GoogleReCaptcha.GoogleReCaptcha))));   I also edited my question to show the error

Comment: Check your assembly reference and empty your temp folder. While, you're at it, set it up on full IIS if you can. Something weird about the way you're running this project. Can't help you if you don't show your code-behind.